# How to get connection status of Bluetooth device for Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

How to get the connection status of a bluetooth device for android i.e. "connected", "disconnected", "disconnecting" or "connecting" for the API level 7 onwards?

I am dying searching a lot on this issue but found nothing on regard of this. Neither am I able to disconnect a device which is not connected in my app because I don't know if it is connected or not.

I can know if a device is connected in my App using the `Intent.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED` and `Intent.ACL_DISCONNECTED` , and I get the interrupt or alert when I get a device connected or disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to detect whether a bluetooth device is connected. You can only detect connect/disconnect events.